# Push notification permission alert does not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In the following code, the device token is gotten.
But Alert View which confirms push notification permission does not appear.
Maybe for that reason, although sending push notification, it does not reach the device.
Do you have any idea why the Alert does not appear?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [deviceToken.description stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"DeviceToken: %@", deviceTokenString);    
}
```

- Deployment target is iOS8.0.
- Push Notifications status in Provisioning Profile is "Enabled".

Comment: Implement the `(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error` as well! Are you running on a real device or the simulator?

Comment: Might as well that you once confirmed or denied. There's a guide to follow about that (I think removing the app), but unsure.

Comment: Things to remember:
- If you are running this on the simulator you will never reach `didRegisterForRemoteNOtificatiosnWithDeviceToken`. 
- Also, if you were asked before if you wanted to accept notifications from the app, the device will "store" the answer so it wont ask the user every time.

Comment: Use Settings to remove permission for your app and you will see that alert again.